# Silent truncation using OpenRowSet to Bulk Load data

Tags: sql-server

I‌‌ have to load CSV data into SQL server table using OpenRowSet.
‌ I have installed the AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe, Access and SQL server 2014 both are 64-bit. 
Also enabled below settings,

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
reconfigure with override
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
reconfigure with override
```

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL'
,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt,*.csv)}','select * fromD:\MYDATA\go\test.CSV')
```

‌‌

D‌ata was also getting loaded into the table, but some of my rows in CSV have data more than what is defined in the schema of the table (Test) and I don't want to change column size in the table(Test) So SQL started giving errors related to truncation. Without using OpenRowSet earlier I used to use "Set ANSI WARNINGS OFF" to do silent truncation. But with OpenRowSet if I use this command then it gives below error

> Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query.‌‌

I want to use OpenRowSet because it is very fast. So can anyone please help me on how I can do silent truncation using OpenRowSet.

Comment: You might try a column list, with expressions to truncate values as desired.

Comment: @DanGuzman Can you please provide a example.

Comment: For example: `INSERT INTO Test(SmallColumn) SELECT CAST(BigColumn AS varchar(10)) FROM ...`